# Jenkins & JUnit : Path to XML impossible to set

Tags: xml, junit, jenkins

The question may sound silly, but I haven't found how to configure the XML report path in the Post-build Junit task after an hour of manipulations.
I generate the JUnit test report (the XML file) here :

> C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\UPWSP\workspace\up\UPWSP\current\06-Java Unit Testing\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml

And the job using the XML has its worskpace at this path :

> C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\UPWSP - Tests JUnit\workspace\

The JUnit report post-build task seems to take only relatives path and I already tried with

> ../../UPWSP/up/UPWSP/current/06-Java Unit Testing/junit/TESTS-TestSuites.xml
>
> **../../UPWSP/up/UPWSP/current/06-Java Unit Testing/junit/TESTS-TestSuites.xml

It always tells me '..' is not a valid path, and an absolute path won't work either.
Any idea of how I should use it?

Answer (score 14):

AFAIK, the path for the JUnit XML file has to be a *sub-directory* of your project. It should *not* be outside the job's workspace. Once you have created a directory inside workspace, say for example, *junit-test*, then the following should work as expected when specified in `Test report XMLs` section: `junit-test\TESTS-TestSuites.xml`

Comment: Jenkins can reach anywhere under $WORKSPACE - a sub-directory is not required.

Answer (score 6):

You can use wildcards like `**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml` or, in your case, `**/junit/*.xml`

Answer (score 3):

This is a work around and not an actual answer. I had to copy the xml to the job directory with a xcopy command line. My job is now working, but that's not how I expected things to work

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the "Test report XMLs" field (assuming you are on windows machine):

```
up\UPWSP\current\06-Java Unit Testing\junit\*.xml
```

I am not clear about "job using the XML" part you detailed. How is that related to the job generating the junit reports?

Comment: The reports generate a xml file, and I use it in the same job :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `junit` step into `dir` step like this:

```
pipeline{
  stages{
    stage("Run tests")
      steps{
        echo "Here generate some test_result.xml files in /some/path"
      }
  }
  post {
    success {
      dir('/some/path')
      {
        junit '**/test_result.xml'
      }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know what version this was tested with, but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: 2.332.2 - it works. Helped me with the case when k8s agent steps were used inside common bare-metal agent steps. env.WORKSPACE inside k8s agent steps was pointing to workspace of bare-metal agent for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

On windows, use explorer and go to your installation directory. Something like this C:\Users\me\.jenkins\workspace\PetClinic\target. Add a new folder. Go back to Jenkins dashboard. If you see a red x in post-build actions, click it. Reselect the options and add the new path **/target/newfolder/*.xml. 
edit: Find the folder that has the tests in it from the cloned repo. Use that folder, in my case it is surefire-reports

Comment: That ship has sailed! I don't have the environment to test things anymore. This questions is from 2014 :)